# Volume Units – how much is EL?

Tags: abbreviation

I have bought a product. In the use instructions, it is said to add

> 3 EL Wasser und 3 EL Öl

Now, I did a little bit of search, and EL definitely is not short for *Exaliter*. How much is it then?

Comment: I'd LOVE to have to put 3 exaliters of water and oil into a meal...

Comment: it's not a proper unit. it's the same nonsense as all imperial units.

Comment: @Dbl Imperial units can actually be transformed into metric ones by simple multiplication with constants. That put them above *Esslöffel* in forms of definition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

El stands for Esslöffel, meaning tablespoon. Unlike US volumetric measurements, it's not strictly standardized, but 15 ml per tablespoon is the usual amount.

---

For the sake of completeness:

- Tl / TL = Teelöffel, teaspoon, – 5 ml
- El / EL = Esslöffel, tablespoon – 15 ml
- Msp. = Messerspitze, tip of a knife – the (very vague) amount you pick up with the tip of a knife
- Pr. = Prise, pinch – what you pick between two or three fingertips

Comment: 15 ml sounds far too much to me for a liquid. Perhaps a _gehäufter Eßlöffel_ of some powder is that much, but for water and oil, my tablespoons have room for perhaps 3 to 5 ml. I’m guessing the product from the question is something like _Knorr Salatkrönung_, and I heavily doubt one package of those is intended for 90 ml of liquid …

Comment: @chirlu, then you have particularly small tablespoons: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Küchenmaße#Besteck

Comment: As [this useful Google search shows](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=size+of+tablespoon+in+ml&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=YL07V8q0MsKk0ATvsZbIAw), a "standard" tablespoon is indeed 14.7868 ml!

Comment: That’s US standard, though. – Note in the Wikipedia article that it distinguishes between old-style and modern spoons, the latter being both smaller and flatter, and gives a volume of around 10 ml for the “modern” spoon. In a different article (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essbesteck#Verwendung_als_Ma.C3.9Feinheit), a “modern” spoon is estimated to contain 7.5 ml.

Comment: In favour of the 15 ml interpretation, though: On the _Salatkrönung_ packaging, it says “Inhalt: 10 g; ergibt 90 ml”.

Comment: @chirlu Typisch! Nicht mal die Loeffel sind was sie mal waren! ;)

Comment: @chirlu oh. it's US "standard". now it makes sense why it does not make sense.

Comment: For the sake of complete completeness, you should add the difference between *gehäuften* and *gestrichenen Ess-/Teelöffeln* ;)

Comment: @Jan I'd love to watch you add *a heaping tablespoon of water* ;-) Even with strong surface tension...

Comment: @Stephie If we’re going there, please show be *eine Prise Wasser* ;)